# About Ultrarradicals

Tags: polynomials, radicals, book-recommendation

I would like to know what is an ultrarradical (Bring Jerrard is one example that I heard of) and hypergeometric series and how mathematicians discorvered it. Or at least a book or an article recommendation.

Thanks